# Other than plugging in a usb device, what else can result in the same sound being played?

Tags: windows-10, usb

I am using Windows 10 and I am well familiar with the two sounds being played when I plug in and unplug a USB device.

The reason I'm well familiar with them is that they are being played multiple times a night, without me messing with any USB device at all. Not every night though, but when the plug in or out sound is played, the other one usually follows a bit later.

I have installed [USBLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html) and set it to start upon login so it is always running. I did this the other day and after this I have not heard the sound.

... until just now. I quickly opened up the program from the tray ... and nothing. The list is empty.

Just to ensure it is actually monitoring for this while in the tray I restarted my computer, unplugged the Xbox One controller wireless usb dongle I have attached, I heard the sound, plugged it back in, another sound, opened up the program and it lists the two events just fine.

So my question is basically, these sounds (you can hear them [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKDh-9bwDsc), they're the first two sounds being played), can they originate from something *other* than plugging in or unplugging a usb device?

I'm at a loss at what to look for.

I have a Oculus Rift headset attached with all its sensors, could it be that it is updating the device so that the *software* in the device keeps disconnecting and connecting, but that the *hardware* is still connected, and this is registered somewhat in the same manner but not actually as a USB device being plugged in or out? I don't know, just a thought.

Comment: I'm skeptical if this question is actually 100% on topic here as it may sound like I'm asking for "please list all the possible ways this sound can be played". If you think the *question* is on topic, but the question *form* is off topic, please let me know. Also, if the entire thing is off topic, just vote to close it and I'll take care of deleting it myself. As I'm said, I'm not entirely convinced it is good form for this site.

Comment: Related: https://www.maketecheasier.com/stop-random-usb-connect-noises-windows/ but that is a very normal situation. Interference in a cable, flash drives broken, etc.

Comment: But to reply to the question, every PnP device connected/disconnected do the same sound. Not sure if hot-swapping hard drives is on the list too.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Would you know where I can see this happening, or monitor it?

Comment: Device Manager would be the first attempt if the sounds are predictable. If not, try to use [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) which you can filter devices by "Last Plug/Unplug Date". That way you can see the last devices plugged in/out. While USBLogView would do the same, I would try that one so it does log all devices that are plugged in/out.

Comment: [This](https://forums.oculusvr.com/community/discussion/42165/breakthrough-for-many-issues-usermodepowerservice) might actually be my issue. I will try the steps outlined there.

Comment: You can easily verify if the Oculus is doing this by disconnecting it for the night. See also if you can see connect/disconnect in the Event Viewer.

Comment: I remember with my Rift I would get lots of sensor disconnects as Windows had set the USB device to be turned off to save power. You can find the option in Device Manager -> USB controllers -> Right Click + Properties (on all the connected USB devices plugged in) -> Power Management then uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".